# How to pass a parameter to an Oracle Apex application process?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex 5. I have an ajax routine that gets a list of room numbers:

```
apex.server.process("getRooms"
                   ,{pageItems:"#P1_ROOM"}
                   ,{dataType:"text"})
  .done(function(pReturn){ 
   -- my processing code --
})
```

Instead of hard coding #P1_ROOM, can I pass a parameter? (I have many room number drop downs on the page.) Can I also somehow pass additional parameters, like the div id in which the form field #P1_ROOM exists?

Also, the 'getRooms' application process references the same hard coded value for the form field: :P1_ROOM. Can I parameterize this also?

```
declare
    roomList varchar2(32000) := '';
begin
  IF(:P1_ROOM)!= ' ' THEN
      for c in
          (select distinct room_id from RTP_PERSON_VIEW
          where upper(room_id) LIKE upper(:P1_ROOM) || '%'
          order by room_id)     
      loop
        roomList :=  roomList || '~' || c.room_id;
      end loop;
      htp.prn( roomList );
  END IF;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Apex JavaScript API syntax `$v("P1_ROOM")` to pass the parameter.

You can pass a maximum of 10 values like this:

```
apex.server.process ( 
  "MY_PROCESS"
,   {   x01: $v("P1_ROOM")
    ,   x02: $v("P1_CATS")
    ,   x03: $v("P1_DOGS")
    ,   x04: 'my last variable'
    }
 , { dataType: 'text'
 ,success: function(pData){alert(pData)}
}
);
```

[Here](https://ruepprich.wordpress.com/2013/01/11/getting-and-setting-apex-page-item-values-using-v-s-v2/) you have more examples on how to use the Apex JavaScript API.

[Here](https://atulley.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/passing-more-than-10-values-with-apex-server-process/) you can find a tutorial on how to pass more than 10 values with apex.server.process

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check this out.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way:

```
apex.server.process ( 
  "MY_PROCESS"
, { pageItems: "#P152_ID,#P152_ID_OBJ,#P152_ORDER_DT,#P152_SUMM" }
, { dataType: 'text'
, success: function(pData){alert(pData)}
} );
```